# Access Variable from a different function without creating global variables

Tags: javascript, scope, global-variables, phantomjs, casperjs

I've recently started using CasperJS to do web automation, and something is confusing me a little.

How do access local variables from one function to another? For example:

```
casper.start('http://google.com', function(){
    var someVar = 20;
});

casper.thenOpen('http://google.com/analytics', function(){
    // How can I access someVar?jav
});
```

I know `someVar` is not in scope in the second function, but how do I access `someVar` in the second function without defining globals?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without using Globals you say, then create a third function (bean) which would have `var someVar = 20;` local variable and provide `getter` and `setter` functions to use by others.

```js
var SharedSpace = (function(){
 var shared = 20; //initialization
 return {
   getShared: function(){
                      return shared;
                   },
   setShared: function(val){
                      shared = val;
                   }
   }
})();

(function(){
    alert(SharedSpace.getShared());
    SharedSpace.setShared(500)
})();

(function(){
    alert(SharedSpace.getShared());
    SharedSpace.setShared(400)
})();

(function(){
    alert(SharedSpace.getShared());
    SharedSpace.setShared(10)
})();
```

Comment: And put the all code in anonymous function to create a local scope so the variables wont be in global scope.

Comment: Ah, now this is a nice example. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

What about using an object to get a certain variable as property:

```
var myObj = {};

casper.start('http://google.com', function(){
    myObj.someVar = 20;
});

casper.thenOpen('http://google.com/analytics', function(){
    console.log(myObj.someVar);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't do this so that it is clean and makes sense. Defining a global variable is the only clean way. You could of course put the variable on the `casper` object, but that is not clean as it might interfere with the CasperJS functionality if you use wrong variable names. I only do this when I define helper functions for `casper`.

```
casper.start('http://google.com', function(){
    this.someVar = 20;
});

casper.thenOpen('http://google.com/analytics', function(){
    this.echo(this.someVar);
});
```